# POST xml with cURL

Tags: xml, curl

I have a customer that is requesting we e-invoice with xml files. I already have the app that creates the files. I can POST them successfully using the HttpRequester browser plug in. However, when I attempt to POST the xml file using cURL it successfully transmits. However, my customer isn't able to use the xml file. When they run their process it returns errors.

the error log returned:

1451410669881-xxxxxxt_einvoice.xml - Content is not allowed in prolog.
Failed to move file 1451410669881-market_einvoice.xml to folder .\AXPIM\failed

Comment: The prologue should be the <?xml version="1.0"?> first line. The second has the slashes going the wrong way. That is the first thing I noticed.

Comment: It looks like there's text before `<?xml` in that file, which is not allowed. How are you posting? Is the XML you generate correct (`xmllint`)?

Comment: here's the first 3 lines of my xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/InvoiceDetail.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="2015-02-19T10:08:13-6:0014754860129108" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2015-02-19T10:08:13-6:0">

If I POST the file using HttpRequester browser plugin the xml file processes without any errors. Only when I POST the xml file using cURL it returns the errors. I'm POST the same file. One POST method is OK the other fails.